# App Deploying on Internal storage in Physical Device

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp

i am building an UWP App which i am targeting to work on both Mobile and PC,

Now Problem is - 
After i clean install my PC (due to some reasons), i reinstall my copy of visual studio 2015 .
Now when i deploy app to my mobile (ARM) device i deploying automatically to internal storage, but previously before clean installing PC it deploy app on Mobile SD Card automatically .

Here is something which i need to configure in visual studio ?

Screeenshot

[image: Deploying]

In Mobile i also set to deploy app to SD Card

[image: Mobile]

Comment: What's your OS version? And current visual studio 2015 version? Previous visual studio version? You could start visual studio and click 'Help - About Microsoft Visual Studio' to check its version.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Mobile OS is Windows 10.0.15254.158, Desktop OS Windows 10.0.16299.192 and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, visual studio is same which i was using previously , something configuration is disturbed because now all projects (inc.uwp, winphone8.1) now deploy on phone internal storage. My pc is not support hyper v and phone memory is also running out i deploy multiple projects on it because after uninstalling some files still left on it

Comment: I already have stand alone setup of vs 2015 update 3 so no difference on installation, i have also vs 2017 installed but i forget to check on it . I will check on it and comment again